# Windows 8.1 occassional boot delay

Tags: boot, windows-8.1

From time to time (not always) when booting, Windows sticks for about 15-20 seconds on the initial black boot screen with the logo (right after the BIOS start) before showing the spinning circle under the logo and start booting, i.e. the circle is shown with the delay. On the next boot the circle can be shown right away.

There are no errors in the Event Viewer.

Updates are not installed when the delay happens (I have them installed on demand).

HDD light is off during the delay.

I am new to Windows 8.1, so I wanted to ask whether this is a normal process, or is this something that requires checking?

Comment: Could be the last step of installing some updates (which happens on restart). 15 seconds is not a long time to wait or be worried about :/

Comment: I would do a chkdsk /f/r and a sfc /scannow in the command prompt, if neither shows any errors I would use a utility to check for bad sectors or a failing hard drive.

Comment: try to capture a boot trace of the hang issue: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions.

I have executed many tests, and I conclude that the cause of the delay is a USB hub. So the delay happens when Windows detects/enumerates (not sure) the hub devices. When the hub is off, there is no delay during the boot.

Answer (score 0):

Open *Task Manager*. On the *Startup* tab, order by *Startup impact*. It is possible there are processes with high impact, *some* of which could be disabled from that tab. Antivirus applications often *do* delay startup a bit, but *do not disable an AV*; allow it to check files.

My PC came with numerous utilities added by the manufacturer; many were not needed. Research any questionable ones online; disabling the wrong application can cause issues.